# Jenkins Declarative pipeline docker: command not found

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, dockerhub

I have installed Jenkins locally on my machine. I pulling some source code from my github repository which has a Docker file in the root directory. I want to build and docker image and push it to docker hub but my build fails with the following message...

```
docker build -f myapp-web:latest . \n
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/MyApp@tmp/durable-ee9851e9/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
```

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    tools {
        maven 'maven_3.6.1'
        jdk 'jdk8'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                withMaven(maven: 'maven_3.6.1', mavenSettingsConfig: '5d7a8237-6d6a-4189-a907-518900dc7755') {
                    sh "mvn clean install "
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build Image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'docker build -f myapp-web:latest .'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy Image') {
            steps {
                withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: "docker-hub", url: ""]) {
                    sh 'docker push myapp-web:latest'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Docker is install and running on my local machine and Jenkins is configured with the following plugin
Docker pipeline
Docker plugin

Any ideas greatly appreciated

Comment: have you checked the value of `$PATH` through jenkins ? maybe it does not include the path where docker binary is.

Comment: I have not setup a $PATH variable through Jenkins...Are you talking about Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties -> Environment Variables

Comment: Iv added  environment{
        PATH = "/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
    } to the script and It seems to have resolved the above error but now Im getting "    Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post"

Comment: So now the next step is to add user jenkins  (or whatever user used in the pipeline )to the docker group so he can be able to use docker comands, using `usermod -aG docker $USER`

Comment: Big thanks! Looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting `docker: command not found` through the pipeline although its already installed on the same node where the pipeline is running, you need to ensure that the pipeline is reading the correct `$PATH` environment where the docker binary should be exist.

For the second issue you have mentioned

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

you need to add the user that is being used within the pipeline to the docker group so it can run docker commands using:

```
usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Comment: Although Iv marked your answer as correct. Im using macOS and usermod command is not found. Im trying to figure out the equivalent to usermod -aG docker $USER on mac. First I logged $USER in the Jenkins file and saw it was Jenkins. Then I created a group docker and added that user . But im still getting the permission error

Comment: For editing the user group try this might help: https://superuser.com/q/214004/233127 also you might need to restart Jenkins or docker after the modification